# How do I sort Reminders in OS X?

Tags: macos, reminders

One can enter reminders in OS X in the Reminders app. But how can they be sorted by name or date? I can't seem to find out how.

Answer (score 3):

Afaik there's is no "automatic" sort. But you can drag them in the order you want.